# Error on page lightning conponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, error-messages

I have a community page where I have a lightning component which gives me an error in the builder. This was a component which I removed from the page.

I copied the component into another component with another name and the original component is not on the page, but the new component with some adjustments.

It seems like I cant edit the new component anymore in the console when this error appeared.  I get the following error, any ideas?

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'identityRequest' of component 'markup://c:OpleidingenListCmp {20:358;a}' is not visible to 'markup://c:OpleidingenListCmp {20:358;a}'. Failing descriptor: {c:OpleidingenListCmp}
```

Here is the markup

```
  <aura:component controller="picklistController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="opleidingenList" type="Opleiding__c[]"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="opleiding" type="Opleiding__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="memory" type="Opleiding__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler event="c:CategorieChange" action="{!c.UpdateList}"/>
    <aura:registerEvent name="appEvent" type="c:OpleidingId"/>  
    <aura:registerEvent name="initPicklist" type="c:initPicklist"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Doelgroep" type="String" default="Tennisleraren"/> 
    <aura:handler event="c:EventUnhideP1" action="{!c.toggle}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="myCurr" type="Decimal" default="50"/>
    <p aura:id="textopleiding" >  
        <br/>
        <c:SearchBar />
        <br></br>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.opleidingenList}" var="opleiding">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <p><b>{!opleiding.Opleiding__c}</b></p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>  
                            <tr >
                                <td data-label="" class="slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Docent(e):</div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="" class="slds-size_3-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!opleiding.Docent_e__r.Name}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="" class="slds-size_2-of-12">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Locatie:</div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="">
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{!opleiding.Locatie__c}</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
..
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                                <label class="{!'slds-checkbox' + (v.identityRequest.Marketing__c ? ' checkbox-checked' : '')}">
                                                    <ui:inputCheckbox text="{!opleiding.Id}" aura:id="boxPack" value="" name="{!opleiding.Opleiding__c}" change="{!c.checkboxSelect}" class="input_class_checkbox" />
                                                    <!--<span class="slds-checkbox-#faux"></span>-->
                                                </label>
                                               <img src="{!$Resource.Inschrijven}"/>
                                                <span class="slds-form-element__label text"> </span>   
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr></hr>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>  
                </div>          
            </div> 
        </aura:iteration>
    </p>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Can you post the component markup code for the failing component.

Comment: Yeah. check the attribute name, spelling and remember attribute name is case sensitive

Comment: @RedDevil  I added the markup

Comment: You should use `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layoutItem` instead of `<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters"><div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `<aura:attribute>` for the "identityRequest" variable. At the moment it does not look like you have one which is why it could be failing.